# Close collapse panel onClick - Ant Design Collapse

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

So make the panel close automatically after clicking on the button using `onClick` function. I found this [useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62669428/ant-design-collapse-close-on-button) but I have no idea what went wrong after adding into my code.
Here's my `custom collapse` code in **./CustomCollapse.js**:

```js
const CustomCollapse = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);


  useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(props.isOpened)
  }, [props.isOpened])

  const setFun1= () => setDisabled(prev => !prev);
  const setFun2= () => () => setOpen(prev => !prev);

  const combineFunc = () =>{
    setFun1();
    setFun2();
  }
  

  return (
    <StyledCollapse activeKey={open} onChange={combineFunc()}>
      <AntCollapse.Panel
        header={props.header}
        key="1"
        showArrow={false}
        bordered={false}
        extra={
          <span>
            <span style={{ color: "#0076de", float: "right" }}>
              {followed ? <div id={styles.emptyBox}><p>+10</p></div> : <img src={tickIcon} alt="" style={{height:'1.2em', marginLRight:'10px', width:'auto', objectFit:'contain'}} />}
              {disabled ? <div id={styles.themeBox}><p>+10</p></div> : <img src={arrowDownIcon} alt="" style={{height:'1.2em', marginLRight:'10px', width:'auto', objectFit:'contain'}} />}
            </span>
          </span>
        }
      >
      {props.children}
      </AntCollapse.Panel>
    </StyledCollapse>
  );
};
```

Here's where I want to change the state which is in **./FollowTelegram.js**:

```js
const [open, setOpen] = useState(["1"]);
const handleSubmit = () => {
    setOpen([]);
  }

//{...somecode}

  <AntCollapse isDisabled={disabledCollapse} isFollowed={followed} isOpened={open} id={styles.telegramHeader1} header="Follow XXX on Telegram Announcement Channel">
          <Row type='flex' align='middle' justify='center'>
            //Here's where I change the state
            <Button onClick={() => {setFollowed(); toggleDisabledCollapse(); handleSubmit();}} style={buttonStyle2} disabled={clicked}>Continue</Button> 
          </Row>
  </AntCollapse>
```

Comment: in `CustomCollapse,js` why u using `useEffect` to pass prop variables to state? Why not just do `const [open, setOpen] = useState(props.isOpened)`? Also, what is this `setDisabled` method? You have not created it or, atleast, do not show us in the code. `followed` and `disabled` variables - they do not exist... I am confused where you are pulling your values form as they dpo not exist in that file you specified. ALSO specify what happends when you run this code - what errors you get, what behavior?

Comment: My first observation is that setOpen(props.isOpened) makes no sense. Just use props.isOpened directly. No need for useState and useEffect there.

Comment: Also onChange={combineFunc()} is wrong use. You just want to pass in the function like onChange={combineFunc}, not call the function.

Comment: combineFunc calls setFun2();, but setFun2(); only returns a new function and does nothing otherwise. Maybe you meant to return that function, and use it in onChange={combineFunc()}?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a handler function and pass it to the inline property.

You need to change the `open` state so in the `FollowTelegram.js`:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

const handleSubmit = () => {
   setOpen(prevState => !prevState); // for toggling
   // or set the `open` to true/false it depend on your requirement
   // setOpen(true) / setOpen(false)
   setFollowed();
   toggleDisabledCollapse();
}

// rest of the codes ...

<AntCollapse isDisabled={disabledCollapse} isFollowed={followed} isOpened={open} id={styles.telegramHeader1} header="Follow XXX on Telegram Announcement Channel">
  <Row type='flex' align='middle' justify='center'>
    <Button onClick={handleSubmit} style={buttonStyle2} disabled={clicked}>Continue</Button> 
  </Row>
</AntCollapse>
```